# com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxLazyException] Unexpected character '=' (code 61) (expected a name start character) error in confluence

Tags: confluence, confluence-macros

I created and uploaded a confluence macro plugin. On manage app screen it show plugin has been installed and enabled, however, in logs I see below error. Also, the macro is not rendering as expected. I tried to get some help on google but could not find any relevant information.

[xhtml.view.macro.DefaultViewMacroWrapper] wrapMacro Error parsing macro [NEWJiraMIIssuesConsolidated] because of [[com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxLazyException] Unexpected character '=' (code 61) (expected a name start character)"

Answer (score 0):

It might be that the content is not properly escaped in the code and it tries to show some special characters on a page.

I had an ampersand symbol (&) in a table and then I tried to use page properties report to show that content from that cell, and it was failing with a similar error.